# How to find out the missing numbers from a list of numbers containing 1 to 25 in UIPATH

Tags: uipath

I have a list of numbers from 1 to 25 among which a few numbers are missing. How can I get the missing numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to find the missing number... if its not present fill it with the number by storing in array